# Dynamic comments in Tableau

Tags: dynamic, comments, data-analysis, tableau-desktop

Does anyone know how to create dynamic comments in Tableau, consisting of some metrics (aggregated) from the data, that are refreshed every time the dataset is refreshed?

Comment: be more specific, share some sample image to explain

Comment: Two Tableau features that you probably should read about are annotations and tooltips. In both cases, you can insert field names in angle brackets that replaced by data values - look for an insert button in the dialog boxes. You can do the same in title bars also.